# Is it possible to `unset` a library target in cmake?

Tags: cmake

Please see the below minimal example,

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(MY_DIR "/path/one")
add_library(third-party-lib INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(third-party-lib PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
                                                 ${MY_DIR}/usr/local/include)
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo third-party-lib)

add_subdirectory(bar)
```

bar/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(MY_DIR "/path/two")
add_library(third-party-lib INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(third-party-lib PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
                                                 ${MY_DIR}/usr/local/include)
add_executable(bar main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bar third-party-lib)
```

I have a third party imported library that have properties that depend on a certain variable, in the case of the minimal example it's `MY_DIR`, I want to set this variable differently for different targets. Is this possible to achieve by "unset"-ing the imported target?

The current minimal example results in `add_library cannot create imported target "third-party-lib" because another target with the same name already exists.` I tried something like adding `unset(third-party-lib)` on top of bar/CMakeLists.txt, and I still see the same error.

To provide more context for the real situation, the third party library I need to link to is called by `find_package`, there are various versions of this third party library that are compiled with different compilers, but only one single config.cmake file is provided, and the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` has a variable in it's path that determines which version of the third party library it points to. I want to be able to compile one of my target linking to this third party library that is compiled by compiler A, and compile another one of my target linking to this third party library that is compiled by compiler B.

Comment: "Is this possible to achieve by "unset"-ing the imported target?" - You cannot unset any target. The IMPORTED target has **local visibility**: it is accessible only by `CMakeLists.txt` defining it and other `CMakeLists.txt` included via `add_subdirectory`. For avoid conflicts you could move `add_library(third-party-lib INTERFACE IMPORTED)` in the main `CMakeLists.txt` to be **below** `add_subdirectory(bar)`, so `bar/CMakeLists.txt` won't see that target definition.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes I understand that will work but that requires a huge refactoring... I guess if it's not possible to unset any target then we will have to do it